# gnuplot: Defined radius in data is different from generated plot

Tags: gnuplot

This script used to give me the correct plot, now it does not... If I run this script:

```
$DATA<<EOD
0.00,0.00,0.7000,90.0000,114.0000
0.00,0.00,1.0000,114.0000,162.0000
0.00,0.00,1.0000,162.0000,234.0000
0.00,0.00,1.0000,234.0000,330.0000
0.00,0.00,1.0000,330.0000,450.0000
EOD
set datafile separator comma
set style data circles
set term windows
unset xtics; unset ytics; unset x2tics; unset y2tics
set grid noxtics
set grid noytics
set xrange [-1.5:1.5]
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]
set border 0
set colorsequence classic
set title "{/Tahoma=22 Plotting with Pies}" textcolor rgb "0xE25822" rotate by 0
set key inside top right opaque fc rgb "0xFFFFFF"
set label 1 "Alpha\n1" at -0.27,1.27 center font "Tahoma:Bold,12" front
set label 2 "Bravo\n2" at -0.97,0.87 center font "Tahoma:Bold,12" front
set label 3 "Charlie\n3" at -1.24,-0.40 center font "Tahoma:Bold,12" front
set label 4 "Delta\n4" at 0.27,-1.27 center font "Tahoma:Bold,12" front
set label 5 "Echo\n5" at 1.13,0.65 center font "Tahoma:Bold,12" front
plot $DATA every ::0::0 using 1:2:3:4:5 with circles fillstyle solid fc rgb "0x007FFF" title "Alpha (6.67%)",\
$DATA every ::1::1 using 1:2:3:4:5 with circles fillstyle solid fc rgb "0x3CD070" title "Bravo (13.33%)",\
$DATA every ::2::2 using 1:2:3:4:5 with circles fillstyle solid fc rgb "0x738678" title "Charlie (20.00%)",\
$DATA every ::3::3 using 1:2:3:4:5 with circles fillstyle solid fc rgb "0xE25822" title "Delta (26.67%)",\
$DATA every ::4::4 using 1:2:3:4:5 with circles fillstyle pattern 4 title "Echo (33.33%)"
```

I get a plot like this: [image: Circle with different radius as data]

Notice in the plot that I have the crosshair on the top of the piece for "Alpha" and I get a reading of 0.0024,1.011 (give or take)

My question is: Why do I get a radius in my plot of 1 (for Alpha) and 1.4 (for the rest of the pieces) if my data says 0.7 for Alpha and 1.0 for the rest of the pieces.

PS: The position of the labels seem erratic as well, but I would like to solve one problem at a time.

Thank you,
Roberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of a circle in gnuplot is always specified in terms of its x-axis coordinate range.  If the x and y axes have different scales, then the vertical extent of that circle will be something else.  From the documentation:

```
gnuplot> help circle
    

 Syntax:
     set object <index> circle {at|center} <position> size <radius>
         {arc [<begin>:<end>]} {no{wedge}}
         {<other-object-properties>}

 The position of the circle is specified by giving the position of the center
 center followed by the radius.  The keywords `at` and `center` are synonyms.
 In 2D plots the position and radius may be given in any coordinate system.
 See `coordinates`. Circles in 3D plots cannot use graph coordinates.
```

> ```
>  In all cases the radius is calculated relative to the horizontal scale of the
>  axis, graph, or canvas.  Any disparity between the horizontal and vertical
>  scaling will be corrected for so that the result is always a circle.
> ```

```
 If you want to draw a circle in plot coordinates (such that it will appear as
 an ellipse if the horizontal and vertical scales are different), use
 `set object ellipse` instead.
```

Comment: Ethan, I am not using (and I do not want to use) "set object" to draw a circle.

I am using "set styles data circle", and my $DATA has the coordinates of 0,0 to always start at center, the third parameter in my $DATA is 1 and it is supposed to reflect the radius for my circle and it is not doing that.

You mentioned that a disparity between the x\y scales could cause this (I am looking for this setting). But why the x\y scales will be different on a brand new gnuplot session.?

Roberto

Comment: Yes, but the description applies to all circles.  All circles are visually round.  That necessarily means that the extent on y in y-axis coodinates is irrelevant.   The size of the circle that is drawn depends solely on the x-axis coordinates.    You can make the x and y scales equal with the command `set size ratio -1`.   But if you do not issue that command the scales adjust to make the axis range fit into the plot window, which is something else entirely.

Comment: Ethan, that did the trick!

Now I remember a command called "set size square". My front end program stop issuing it to gnuplot and this is how this whole mess started. 

Thank you for your help
Roberto